# Get the list of values using dom parser in android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, domparser

I have to develop an android application.

Here i have follows following xml format.

```
<Product>
<product name="viki" productid="111">
<ProductType>
<producttype>Nokia</producttype>
<producttype>Samsung</producttype>
</ProductType>
</product>
</Product>
```

Here i have to get the producttype for particluar product.so i have wrote the following code:

```
    if(subCategoryChildNode.hasChildNodes()){
            // parse 'Subcategory' childs
        NodeList productNL = subCategoryChildElmt.getElementsByTagName("product");
        if(productNL.getLength() > 0){

        ArrayList<Product> productAL = new ArrayList<Product>();
        Product productBean = null;
        for(int pCnt=0;pCnt<productNL.getLength();pCnt++){
            Node productNode = productNL.item(pCnt);

            Element productElmt = null;
            // parse 'product' tag attributes 
            if(productNode.hasAttributes()){
                productBean = new Product();
                productElmt = (Element)productNode;
                productBean.setmProductName(productElmt.getAttribute("name"));
            }
            if(productNode.hasChildNodes()){
                NodeList productTypeNL = productElmt.getElementsByTagName("ProductType");
                if(productTypeNL.getLength() > 0){
                    ArrayList<ProductType> ProductTypeAL = new ArrayList<ProductType>();
                    ProductType productTypeBean = null;
                    for(int ptCnt=0;ptCnt<productTypeNL.getLength();ptCnt++){
                    Node productTypeNode = productTypeNL.item(ptCnt);
                    Element productTypeElmt = null;
                    if(productTypeNode.hasChildNodes()){
                        productTypeBean = new ProductType();
                        productTypeElmt = (Element)productTypeNode;
                        productTypeBean.setmProductType(XMLfunctions.getValue(productTypeElmt,"producttype"));
                        System.out.println("Product Types are "+ " "+XMLfunctions.getValue(productTypeElmt,"producttype"));
                        ProductTypeAL.add(productTypeBean);
                    }
                    productBean.setmProductTypes(ProductTypeAL);
                    }
                productAL.add(productBean);
                }
            }
            subCategoryBean.setmProducts(productAL);
        }
        }
    subCategoryAL.add(subCategoryBean);
}
```

Here am getting the value is nokia alone.but i need to display the value nokia,samsung...if i have to run the app means getting single value.but i need to get the list of all values..

What's wrong in my code .. please check and give me solution fot these ???

Comment: In your log, do you see both `Product Types are Nokia` and `Product Types are Samsung`?

Comment: Why not use SAX parser, it is more memory-efficient than keeping everything in memory in a DOM parser - and Android apps have limited memory.

Comment: @NoBugs yes i have tried to that.but i have facing more problems on doing sax parser.that's why i have chossing dom parser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're getting only one `<producttype>` (Nokia) instead of the complete list because you're looping over the length of `<ProductType>` nodes thinking you're looping over the `<producttype>` ones.

So, you need another inner loop to cover all the child product type nodes like

```
for(int ptCnt=0; ptCnt < productTypeNL.getLength(); ptCnt++) {
    Node productTypeNode = productTypeNL.item(ptCnt);
    if(productTypeNode.hasChildNodes()){
        NodeList childProductTypeNL = productTypeNode.getChildNodes();
        System.out.print("Product Types are: ");
        for (int cptCnt=0; cptCnt < childProductTypeNL.getLength(); cptCnt++) {
            productTypeBean = new ProductType();
            productTypeBean.setmProductType (
                            childProductTypeNL.item(cptCnt).getTextContent());
            System.out.print(productTypeBean.getmProductType() + ", ");
            ProductTypeAL.add(productTypeBean);
        }
    }
    productBean.setmProductTypes(ProductTypeAL);
}
```

I've directly used the `Node.getChildNodes()` and `Node.getTextContexnt()` methods, instead of type casting to `Element` first and using its methods or the `XMLfunctions` utility class.

I also recommend using different names for child nodes instead of relying on using a different case to avoid such problems in future. A simple way to avoid name collision (when you're not able to come up with a different name) is to simply use a plural like `<ProductTypes>` for the parent tag.

However, a better approach when you need to parse deep within a DOM tree is to use an `XPath` to directly get the list of nodes you're interested in. I'm not entirely sure what the program does but just to give you an example an `XPath` like

```
 String xpath = "//product[@name=\"viki\"]/ProductType/producttype";
```

would give you the `NodeList` for `<producttype>` nodes directly.

Comment: Thanks for gave me such a wonderful solution.Thanks a lot.Thank you very much.i have learned more from these answer.

Comment: @user2218667 I'm glad to help. Thanks for the appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say one of the problem of your code (might be others), is that you declare your `productTypeBean` and `productTypeElmt` before your for loop, and since it's not required after, it isn't needed.

```
if(subCategoryChildNode.hasChildNodes()){
        // parse 'Subcategory' childs
    NodeList productNL = subCategoryChildElmt.getElementsByTagName("product");
    if(productNL.getLength() > 0){
        ArrayList<Product> productAL = new ArrayList<Product>();
        Product productBean = null;
        for(int pCnt=0;pCnt<productNL.getLength();pCnt++){
            Node productNode = productNL.item(pCnt);

            Element productElmt = null;
            // parse 'product' tag attributes 
            if(productNode.hasAttributes()){
                productBean = new Product();
                productElmt = (Element)productNode;
                productBean.setmProductName(productElmt.getAttribute("name"));
            }
            if(productNode.hasChildNodes()){
                NodeList productTypeNL = productElmt.getElementsByTagName("ProductType");
                if(productTypeNL.getLength() > 0){
                    ArrayList<ProductType> ProductTypeAL = new ArrayList<ProductType>();
                    for(int ptCnt=0;ptCnt<productTypeNL.getLength();ptCnt++){
                        Node productTypeNode = productTypeNL.item(ptCnt);
                        if(productTypeNode.hasChildNodes()){
                            ProductType productTypeBean = new ProductType();
                            Element productTypeElmt = (Element)productTypeNode;
                            productTypeBean.setmProductType(XMLfunctions.getValue(productTypeElmt,"producttype"));
                            System.out.println("Product Types are "+ " "+XMLfunctions.getValue(productTypeElmt,"producttype"));
                            ProductTypeAL.add(productTypeBean);
                        }
                        productBean.setmProductTypes(ProductTypeAL);
                    }
                    productAL.add(productBean);
                }
            }
            subCategoryBean.setmProducts(productAL);
        }
    }
    subCategoryAL.add(subCategoryBean);
}
```